# My popover extends all the whole way down to the bottom of the ViewController

Tags: swift, popover

I have spent a full day now building and re-building a simple popover view. But no matter what I do the popover view extends all the way down to the bottom of the ViewController the popover is displayed in. I'm a newbie but have googled this the whole day and can't find any solutions that works for me. I will appreciate any help! Find my code below:

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,
    UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  {

...

@IBAction func studyButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("StudyPopover", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "StudyPopover" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController

        let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController

        if controller != nil {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .None
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result. The popover is supposed to be 50 by 50, but it extends right down to the bottom of the ViewController.
[image]

Comment: In a way I'm relived there's no answers yet as it seems to confirm that it's not something really obvious and silly I missed. However I wanted to let you know that I'm still stuck on this issue and would still appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally been able to find a solution for this issue. I had a breakthrough when I realised that the popover worked fine when on most device simulations but didn't work for iPhone 6 plus. Then I could narrow down my search for solutions and finally found that I had to add `traitCollection: UITraitCollection` to my `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController` function.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection)  -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .None
}
```

This makes the popover behave the same way either it's on a normal sized iPhone, iPhone 6 plus or iPad device.